# When repeatedly triggering a key mapping, it eventually breaks

Tags: autohotkey

I got this simple key mapping:

`!l::Send, {right}`

Pressing it a few times or holding it down for short periods of times is no problem; it works as you would expect. However, if you hold `alt + l` for a long period of time, the mapping will eventually break, sending the actual key instead of what is mapped to. So in this case it would send a lot of l's when it eventually breaks.

[Gif showcasing it](https://i.gyazo.com/e18012949d6bab726d93075a56f6ba92.mp4),
[Another example](https://i.gyazo.com/606f5980ba172ed22c13976475566bf0.mp4)

The issue isn't unique for this mapping, it happens for a lot of my other simple mappings too.

- Is this a general known issue?
- Is there any fix?

---

*Details*

- My OS is Windows 10

Comment: This is definitely not a new issue. There are a couple of ways to decrease the odds of this happening in my experience, such as by using `SendInput` instead of `Send`, but I'll see if I can find/ create a solution with a closer to 0% breakage rate

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce. If it really is a problem, you could create a timer on the key down event to repeatably send the key, and then stop the timer on the key up event.

Comment: @0x464e That sounds advanced, care to show how in an answer?

Comment: I just realized it would require to be used as a toggle on/off to solve this (without doing any further tricks). So it sounds even worse. Definitely not worth an answer I think. But anyway, as a toggle solution it could be done [this](https://pastebin.com/dyq9qHH3) simply, but really, this is just a very bad solution.